# ServletContextListenercreating maps on startup of Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servletcontextlistener

My application is creating maps of circle and zones at the startup of the applications and setting the servlet context `SCMContextListener.getServletContext().setAttribute("circles", circles);`

This activity is done on the startup once when the application is getting started.Now when a new circle is added in the database we are facing issues to recreate that map as it is created on the startup of the application.Solution to this is we need to take a restart of the application everytime a new circle is added in the database.

To rectify this we created a url and when we hit that url we are first clearing the map we created and setting the map again

But the problem I am facing is

1. When I am using

   `SCMContextListener.getServletContext().removeAttribute("circles");`

`removeAttribute` is not working i.e it is not removing the circle attribute.

2. We are having two server nodes for our application somehow one server is going out of sync and the maps are not created there so the code works on one server and doenot work on the other

Comment: ClassLoader problem?

Comment: You have a clustered application? InMemory?

Comment: Yes we have clustered application.